# data from useQuery i.e. react query is returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

this is my api middleware caller that i have created:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
// /* eslint-disable no-import-assign */
import Axios from 'axios';
import * as queryString from 'query-string';
const caseConverter = require('change-object-case');
import { cleanParams } from '_utilities/common';
import { REQUEST_TYPES } from './constants';
import { useLoginUser } from '_store/user';


interface IAuth {
  method?: string;
  url?: string;
  data?: any;
  params?:any,
  contentType?:string,
  isTransformRequestRequired?:boolean

}

export function apiCaller(
    {
    method = REQUEST_TYPES.GET,
    url = '',
    params = {},
    data = {},
    contentType = 'application/json',
    isTransformRequestRequired = true,
  }:IAuth,
) {
  const user = useLoginUser.getState().user;
  const token = user?.data?.token || ''; 
  // caseConverter.options = {recursive: true, arrayRecursive: true};
  return Axios({
    method,
    url,
    params,
    paramsSerializer: queryParams => queryString.stringify(caseConverter.snakeKeys(cleanParams(queryParams))),
    data,
    transformRequest: [reqData => isTransformRequestRequired
            ? JSON.stringify(caseConverter.toSnake(reqData))
            : reqData],
    transformResponse: [(respData) => 
      { 
         if(typeof respData === 'string')
        return JSON.parse(respData)
        else {
          return respData
        }
      
    }],        
    headers: {
      Authorization: user !== null ? `Token ${ token }` : '',
      'Content-Type': contentType,
    },
    responseType: 'json',
    validateStatus: status => status >= 200 && status < 300,
  })
  .then(({ data: resp }) => resp)
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error,'error')
        // if user session is expired from server and got 401, will logout the user from application
        if(error.response.status === 401) {
          // store.dispatch(logoutSuccess());
        } else {
          throw(error);
        }
      });
}
```

this is where I am calling my apiCaller:

```
import { apiCaller } from '../api-caller';
import { ENDPOINTS, REQUEST_TYPES } from '../constants';
import moment from 'moment';
export const usersApi = async (params:any) => { 
  
  const res =  await apiCaller(
  {
    method: REQUEST_TYPES.GET,
    url: `${ENDPOINTS.USERS}/`,
    params:{
      ...params,
      startDatetime: params.startDatetime ? moment(params.startDatetime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss') : '',
      endDatetime: params.endDatetime ?  moment(params.endDatetime).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss') : '',
    },
  },
);
return res;
}
```

this is where I am using useQuery to fetch data from backend:

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { usersApi } from '_api/users'
import { useAdminUser } from 'pages/Admin/AdminUsers/_store'
const filters = useAdminUser.getState().filters
export const useCreateProfile = () => {
  const query = ['cashierShifts']
  return useQuery(query, () => {
    usersApi(filters)
  })
}
```

and this is where I am using this in my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Table } from 'antd'
import { useCreateProfile } from '_services/CashierProfile'

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Day',
    dataIndex: 'day',
    key: 'day',
  },
  {
    title: 'Shift',
    dataIndex: 'shift',
    key: 'shift',
  },
  {
    title: 'startTime',
    dataIndex: 'start',
    key: 'start',
  },
  {
    title: 'endTime',
    dataIndex: 'end',
    key: 'end',
  },
  {
    title: 'Mart',
    dataIndex: 'mart',
    key: 'mart',
  },
]

const CashierShifts = () => {
  const { data, isError, isLoading, isSuccess } = useCreateProfile()
  console.log(data, 'react-query')
  const [result, setResult] = useState([
    {
      id: 54,
      tile: 'slots 1',
      date: '22-10-2203',
      startTime: '8:00',
      mart: {
        id: 21,
        martName: 'Johar Town',
      },
      endTime: '12:00',
      cashier: {
        name: 'Jamal',
        id: 54,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 54,
      tile: 'slots 1',
      date: '22-10-2203',
      startTime: '8:00',
      mart: {
        id: 21,
        martName: 'Johar Town',
      },
      endTime: '12:00',
      cashier: {
        name: 'Jamal',
        id: 54,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 54,
      tile: 'slots 1',
      date: '22-10-2203',
      startTime: '8:00',
      mart: {
        id: 21,
        martName: 'Johar Town',
      },
      endTime: '12:00',
      cashier: {
        name: 'Jamal',
        id: 54,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 54,
      tile: 'slots 1',
      date: '22-10-2203',
      startTime: '8:00',
      mart: {
        id: 21,
        martName: 'Johar Town',
      },
      endTime: '12:00',
      cashier: {
        name: 'Jamal',
        id: 54,
      },
    },
  ])
  const dataSource = result.map((a) => ({
    day: a.date,
    shift: a.tile,
    start: a.startTime,
    end: a.endTime,
    mart: a.mart.martName,
  }))

  return (
    <div>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CashierShifts
```

the problem is when i am using my react query hook in my component but the data is returning undefined here.

```
 const { data, isError, isLoading, isSuccess } = useCreateProfile()
      console.log(data, 'react-query')
```

Comment: Just remove the `{ }` in the query function that you are passing to `useQuery` so it implicitly returns the data from your fetch function.

Answer (score 0):

```
return useQuery(query, () => {
  return usersApi(filters)
})
```